# What is Completion Stage Meditation also known as Nispannakrama?

Tags: vajrayana, meditation-classification, tantra

In Vajrayana there appears to be many different types and stages of mediation. One form is called "completion stage meditation" also known as nispannakrama.  It appears to be associated with something called Anuttarayoga Tantra. What exactly is "completion stage meditation" and how is it practiced?

Answer (score 1):

According to what I understood from explanations given to me in one of the temples in New Kadampa Tradition, completion meditation is an antidote to potential sideeffects of generation meditation. If practitioner gets too attached to (image of oneself as) one's yidam, they are prescribed certain exercises designed to help them let go.

Comment: I found a copy of "The Life of Milarepa" by Tsangnyon Heruka published by Penguin Classics.  In the introduction it discusses generation and completion stage mediations.  Are you familiar with the text's perspective on these types of meditations?  The story sounds very interesting as well.

Comment: I have read The Life of Milarepa almost 10 years ago, but I still remember it pretty clearly. I don't think I saw Generation/Completion meditation discussed anywhere in the text itself. Maybe in a (modern) introduction? But I may be wrong, it was a while ago and I don't have the text handy these days.